# XMP Metadata from Pdf using PdfSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, metadata, pdfsharp, xmp

I want to read the XMP metadata from PDF documents. I tried to read the data with PDFsharp (http://www.pdfsharp.net/). Most of time it worked well, but in some cases I get this exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReaderException: Cannot handle iref streams. The current implementation of PDFsharp cannot handle this PDF feature introduced with Acrobat 6.
```

I read somewhere that this does not happen in the new version. So I downloaded PdfSharp 1.50.3638-beta (https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharp/1.50.3638-beta).

And yes, now I have no exception. But my new problem is that the function PdfReader.open does not work on some documents. This means that the program never leaves the function.

In some forums I have read that it could be caused by large documents with many images. So I tried to read only the information of the document:

```
PdfDocument pd = PdfReader.Open(s, PdfDocumentOpenMode.InformationOnly);
```

But it still doesn't work. Some ideas how I can read the metadata?

Answer (score 2):

Support for IRef streams is new for PDFsharp 1.50 **beta** and if you have a file that cannot be read then please submit it for examination.

Comment: to download 1.50 go here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharp/1.50.3638-beta. You will need to create a login in order to perform a direct download of the zip archive containing PDFsharp.